# Matlab Unable to Solve two variables from two functions

Tags: matlab

I tried using `solve` and `fsolve` and neither seems to work. Any suggestions? (All of my parenthesis are correct). The first error I get for `solve` is

> Error using `mupadengine/feval_internal`
> Symbolic parameters not supported in nonpolynomial equations.
>
> Error in sym/vpasolve (line 172)
> `sol = eng.feval_internal('symobj::vpasolve',eqns,vars,X0);`
>
> Error in Problem5 (line 28)
> `S=vpasolve(E1==E2,T,0.5)`

The second error I get for `fsolve` is

> No solution found.
> `fsolve` stopped because the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient,
> but the vector of function values is not near zero as measured by the
> value of the function tolerance.

**Using `solve`:**

```
omega12=100.7919; omega21=872.6804;
R=8.314; % L kpa K-1 mol-1
P=13.3; % kpa


syms T x1 

lambda1 = exp(-R*T*(log(x1 + omega12*(1-x1)) + x1*((1-x1-(1-x1)*omega12)/
    (x1+omega12*(1-x1))) + (1-x1)*((-1*(1-x1)+omega21*(1-x1))/(1-x1+omega21*x1))));

lambda2 = exp(-R*T*(log((1-x1)+omega12*x1)+(1-x1)*((1-(1-x1)-x1*omega12)/
    ((1-x1)+omega12*x1)) + x1*((-x1+omega21*x1)/(x1+omega21*(1-x1)))));


psat1=exp(16.6578 - 3674.49 / (( T+ 273.15) + 226.45)); % convert T in C to K

psat2= exp(16.262 - 3799.89 / ((T + 273.15) + 226.35));


E1=lambda1*psat1-P;

E2=lambda2*psat2-P;

E=[E1 E2]

S=vpasolve(E1==E2,T,0.5)
```

**Using `fsolve`:**

```
omega12=100.7919; omega21=872.6804;
R=8.314; % L kpa K-1 mol-1
P=13.3; % kpa


f=@(x)[(exp(-R*x(2)*(log(x(1) + omega12*(1-x(1))) + x(1)*((1-x(1)-(1-x(1))*omega12)/(x(1)+omega12*(1-x(1)))) + (1-x(1))*((-1*(1-x(1))+omega21*(1-x(1)))/(1-x(1)+omega21*x(1))))))
    *(exp((16.6578 - 3674.49) / (( x(2)+ 273.15) + 226.45)))-P;
    (exp(-R*x(2)*(log((1-x(1))+omega12*x(1))+(1-x(1))*((1-(1-x(1))-x(1)*omega12)/((1-x(1))+omega12*x(1))) + x(1)*((-x(1)+omega21*x(1))/(x(1)+omega21*(1-x(1)))))))
    *(exp((16.262 - 3799.89) / ((x(2) + 273.15) + 226.35)))-P]

[x,fval]=fsolve(f,[0.1,10])
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a C++ program, to make a complete search in some area, and it found a solution, after some minor changes to your function, to get the relative precision better.

1. There are restrictions on x1, to ensure, that the argument to log is
   positive, which gives the legal interval for x1=[-0.0100208,
   1.0100208]
2. You subtract P in both expressions for E1 and E2, and you ask for as olution where E1=E2, so P can be removed without modifying
   the solution.
3. After P is removed from both E1 and E2, then take logarithm of E1 and E2    which gives:

   LogE1 =  Loglambda1 + Logpsat1;

   LogE2  =  Loglambda2 + Logpsat2;

All 4 expressions, lambda1,2 and psat1,2 are calculated using exp-function. This cancel out by log, which
will give Loglambda1,2 and Logpsat1,2, which are much smaller values
for MathLab to subtract, and you can solve(LogE1 = LogE2) instead.

This is the equation used in my program, and it draws a fine curve with corresponding values of x and y where E1 == E2

```
omega12 = 100.7919;
mega21 = 872.6804;
R = 8.314; // L kpa K-1 mol-1
P = 13.3;  // kpa

T  = x;
x1 = y;

lambda1 = -R*T * (ln(x1 + (1-x1) * omega12)
          + x1 * ((1-x1-(1-x1)*omega12)/(x1 + (1-x1) * omega12))
          + (1-x1)*((-1*(1-x1)+(1-x1)*omega21)/(1-x1+x1*omega21)));

lambda2 = -R*T * (ln((1-x1)+x1 * omega12)
          + (1-x1) * ((1-(1-x1)-x1* omega12)/((1-x1)+x1 * omega12))
          +  x1    * ((-x1 + x1 *omega21)/(x1+ (1-x1)*omega21)));

psat1 = 16.6578-3674.49/((T+273.15) + 226.45); // convert T in C to K
psat2 = 16.262 -3799.89/((T+273.15) + 226.35);

E1 = lambda1 + psat1;
E2 = lambda2 + psat2;

E1 - E2
```

The problem with the original equation is the exp-function, which makes E1 and E2 extremely sensitive to even the slightest change in T and x1. You loose all precision in the calculation, when first explode the values with exp and then subtract the values you get. Matlab or any other professional tool can not draw this curve using the original formula, but my simple isocurve graph plotter easily finds a solution, after a simple transformation of the equation.

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks so much for doing that! So it looks like you took out the exp completely.

Comment: Exactly. I been thinking about was really going on in the original expression, and I have come to the conclusion that exponential function actually compresses the output because we are at a negative end of the scale, so instead of expanding the value, they are compressed, thereby losing precision...my best guess.